# jquery ajax: how to know if it's waiting for server or server error 503?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-503

I created an ajax call with "timeout" option of 30 seconds and a modal to lock the screen.
If 30 seconds pass or I get respond from server, a callback is returned, and I can check it and unlock the modal (hide it).
But when there is a server error like "server 503", the ajax will wait until the 30 seconds pass and only then it will unlock the screen.
How to catch this a server 503 error with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'Yoururl',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    'YourData': 'YourData'
  },
  success: function(output) {},
  error: function(request, status, error) {
    alert(request.responseText);
    // Check error and do what ever you want to do
  },
});
}
```

Comment: I get alert only when timeout is passed not immediately but chrome returns error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the modal when

1. The server responded with results
2. The server returned error
3. The timeout expired

You can use jQuery AJAX's `timeout` option, in addition with `.always()` promise callback. Below is an example:

```
$.ajax(url, {
  timeout: 30000, // in milliseconds
  // other AJAX options
}).done(function() {
  // Handle the successful response
}).fail(function() {
  // Handle the failures (server errors and timeouts)
}).always(function() {
  // Hide your modal here
});
```

This will make sure that your modal is hidden always, when the AJAX call is complete.

You can read more about the `$.ajax` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I get alert only when timeout is passed not immediately but chrome returns error immediately.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your complete code? I wanna see how did you use timeout.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to read the status to detect 503.   Ive used similar to detect 404 on a past project.

```
        $.ajax({ url: 'somepage.php',
                 type: 'post',
                 data: {'q': ''},
                 success: function(output) {
                    alert(output);
                 },
                 error: function (request, status, error) {
                        // WE HAVE AN ERROR, LETS SEE WHAT SPECIFIC ERROR CODE...
                        if (request.status == 503){
                                // IF THE ERROR CODE IS 503, THEN WE DO SOMETHING HERE...
                                alert('I have the dreaded 503 error!')
                        }
                 },

        })
```

Comment: I get alert only when timeout is passed not immediately but chrome returns error immediately.

Comment: No, I ignored It and amazingly there doesn't to seem a real answer! Did you?